# Is there any way to optimize ManyToOne Relationship using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an employee who can work in multiple departments. I have OneToMany relashionship in Employee and ManyToOne in the Department class.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Size(min = 3, max = 10, message = "Invalid name")
    private String name;
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Department> departments;
}

@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String department;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

The created tables in MySQL looks like the following:

- The employees table:

[image]

- The departments table:

[image]

The problem is that I will have multiple employees and they can have multiple departments. The departments table will be too large and the departments name will be repeated for the different employees as you can see in the picture above I have 2xManagement. My question is if it is possible to create the departments table without the employee_id (only to have the departments name) and do the linking in a separate table with only two properties - employee_id and department_id. Do I need to create a new class for that? How can I optimize this relashionship? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "The departments table will be too large" ?

Comment: Data design doesn't make sense. That should be a many-to-many.

Comment: @Luuk that it will contain a very large amount of data.

Comment: But "a very large amount of date" is something different than "will be too large".  Too large will lead to "disk full" errors (or other errors), "Very large amount of data" should not be a problem for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change solution to @ManyToMany by using weak entity,
References: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: Could you please explain why I need to use @ManyToMany? I am sorry, but I cannot understand it. For me it was that one employee can have multiple departments and one departments can have multiple employees.

Comment: @Sani, as you said. You want:
- one entity can have multiple departments
- one department can have mutilple employees
=> that relationship called many-to-many.
We need to create a new table as a bridge between employee and department (called weak entity). We can naming that table is employee_department (its responsibility is keep relation by contains only id of employee and department)